# Forms not showing changes when run in visual studio 2008

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008

My forms in my vb.net programs in visual studio are not showing the changes I make on them when I run the application. The were working before but eventually just stopped with nothing really done to stop them. I am making changes like changing background color, adding controls like buttons but they only show in the design view but do not show when I run the program. I've tried to clean and build but still showing the same problem. Could someone tell me why this happens and how a fix can be achieved? Thank you

Comment: someone help. this thing is really freaking me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely because you have your build mode set to "release". When you run the debugger it uses the "debug" version. Change your build mode to "debug" and you should see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the file from \bin\Debug and build the application again. It should work fine. And make sure you are on debug mode